# javascript loop strange execute

Tags: javascript, function, loops

Have a loop to set markers on the map:

```
for (i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
    _coord = prj_markers[i];
    alert(i);
    instance.set_marker(instance, provider, i, _coord, divBlock);
}
```

This code alerts "0" once and doing instance.set_marker (as it visible).

Set alert after execution instance.set_marker:

```
for (i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
    _coord = prj_markers[i];        
    instance.set_marker(instance, provider, i, _coord, divBlock);
    alert(i);
}
```

Alerts "6" ONCE, but it must six times alerts. What's going on ?

Comment: We need more code. What's happening in instance.set_marker?

Comment: And what if you will place both alerts in your code?

Comment: there must be something in instance.set_marker, what is its code?

Comment: WTF question is this,, bother to paste complete relevant code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try declaring your initial variable this way at the beginning of your for statement.

```
for (var i = 0; ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The for loop is using `i` as a global variable, so if your `instance.set_marker` function is also using `i` as a global variable and sets its value to something greater than 6 the loop will exit.

Try changing the variable name, and make it a local variable by using the `var` statement:

```
for (var SomeOtherName = 0; SomeOtherName<= 6; SomeOtherName++) {
    _coord = prj_markers[SomeOtherName];        
    instance.set_marker(instance, provider, SomeOtherName, _coord, divBlock);
    alert(SomeOtherName);
}
```